# Getting a string from an ajax post request into spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, post, controller

I'm trying to send some data from a table using ajax post requests but the values from every td element are sent with some weird characters and i'm not sure what would be the right way to send those values.

Here is the ajax request:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tableData").on('click', '.btn', function() {
            // get the current row
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html(); // get current row 2nd table cell TD value
            var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").html(); // get current row 3rd table cell  TD value
            var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").html(); // get current row 3rd table cell  TD value


            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/saveAd",
                data: {
                    col2,
                    col3,
                    col4
                },
                success: function(status) {
                    if (status) {
                        console.log("SUCCESS");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/saveAd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAd(@RequestBody String col1) {
        System.out.println(col1);

        return "home";
    }

For example if col2 = Test1 test1,
               col3 = Test2 test2,
               col4 = Test3 test3
The printed value would be: col2=Test1+test1&col3=Test2+test2&col4=Test3+test3
```

How can i get col2,col3,col4 in a different variable and without those pluses?

Answer (score -1):

If you want all your data in seperate variables you should send your ajax request as below :

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/orders/saveAd",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'col2': "1234",
        'col3': "56",
        'col4': "55"
    },
    success: function (status) {
        if (status) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        }
    }
});
```

Create corresponding request class and change your controller as below :

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/saveAd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveAd(@RequestBody ColRequest cols) {
    System.out.println(cols.getCol2());

    return "home";
}

@Data // comes from lombok for getter setter purpose
class ColRequest {
    private String col2;
    private String col3;
    private String col4;
}
```